# Elasticsearch & Kibana master node failover

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I 'm trying to build a highly available ELK stack.
I'm facing a problem with the master node failover concept.

Let's admit that I have a simple architecture like this :

```
MasterNode1 (A.A.A.A:9200) Elected as master        
MasterNode2 (B.B.B.B:9200) 
    DataNode1
    DataNode2
```

Now if ***MasterNode1*** goes down, how can Kibana know that it has to contact ***MasterNode2*** instead of MasterNode1 (without changing it manually in the kibana config) ?

I think that I'am missing something in this architecture right ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options

1. Look at software such as heartbeat or corosync and associate a virtual IP with one of the nodes. If that node goes down, heartbeat/corosync can switch the virtual IP to another active node.
2. Look at some kind of load balancing technology, either hardware or something like ha-proxy which is intelligent enough to monitor the underlying elasticsearch nodes and prevent access to any that aren't available. This can have the advantage that if you have multiple nodes, they can share some of the workload.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I came across another solution here https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2260. It suggest to set up a client node `(master:false , data:false)` on the same host that kibana is runing on and configure kibana to use this client node. But to me, it seems to be a SPOF solution. I think your solutions are safer. Thank you.